# Rechargeable LiPo for Raspberry Pi without having to be unplugged to be charged

Tags: power-supply, raspberry-pi

I tried researching this online but failed to find exactly what I'm looking for.

I want to have a docking station for my Raspberry pi, where I just connect it to a micro-usb and it'll recharge the LiPo that I have connected to my Pi and when I disconnect, continue to use the LiPo's power.

I am trying to avoid constantly unplugging the LiPo from the Pi and charging it on it's own, then reattaching it to my Pi.

Ideally I'm thinking that maybe there's a circuit that's designed with a micro-usb port on it that when plugged in charges the LiPo and Pi, and when unplugged continues using the LiPo power for the Pi.

My knowledge is slowly growing, so if this isn't possible please teach me as to the problems so I can learn!

Grateful for any tips or guidance

Comment: It is a bit unclear if you want to make your own circuit or buy some off the shelf module. If you are looking for a module then this one has load sharing which switches automatically between USB and battery: https://www.adafruit.com/product/2465

Comment: Sorry you're right, should've made it more clear. Was hoping to get off the shelf and then one day design my own!

Comment: You need to have charge control and supply to component done inside the component - think of how smartphones do it...